# Getting a single row, 5-figure summary result table from T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that correctly results in two columns, `CustID` and `DaysBetweenPurchase`. I am having trouble taking the results table and creating a single row, 5-figure summary of the table. I have tried CTE, wrapping the query, and a temp table.

I have tried to take the original query and wrap it, or use CTE, or temp table, in each case using a second query that calls for the MIN, MAX, and 3 quartiles. I expected a single row table with a value for each of those summary statistics. Here was my result:

> Column 'CTE.Avg_days_between_purchase' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        AVG(DaysBetweenPurchases) AS Avg_days_between_purchase
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             CustomerID,
             DATEDIFF(day, LAG(orderdate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY orderdate), orderdate) AS DaysBetweenPurchases
         FROM
             Sales.SalesOrderHeader sh (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN 
             Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd (NOLOCK) ON sh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID 
    ) AS subquery
    GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT
    MIN(Avg_days_between_purchase) AS Min,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER () AS Q1,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER () AS Median,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER () AS Q3,
    MAX(Avg_days_between_purchase) AS Max
FROM
    CTE;
```

Comment: *Consumable* sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: it would imensly help if you provide tables and data for that query so that we can debug it

Comment: Change MIN(Avg_days_between_purchase) to MIN(Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER() and same with MAX. Then you can use DISTINCT to remove the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be wise to share sample data and expected output for better understanding of the problem.

I am trying to give you a solution based on my understanding of your attempt, To use aggregation (`min()` or `max()`) like this you need to use group by clause. Since you didn't use it I assume that grouping is not your intention. Then you might need to use `min()over()` `max()over()` window functions instead.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        AVG(DaysBetweenPurchases) AS Avg_days_between_purchase
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             CustomerID,
             DATEDIFF(day, LAG(orderdate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY orderdate), orderdate) AS DaysBetweenPurchases
         FROM
             Sales.SalesOrderHeader sh (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN 
             Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd (NOLOCK) ON sh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID 
    ) AS subquery
    GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT
    MIN(Avg_days_between_purchase) over () AS Min,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER () AS Q1,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER () AS Median,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Avg_days_between_purchase) OVER () AS Q3,
    MAX(Avg_days_between_purchase)over() AS Max
FROM
    CTE;
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe this worked. The resulting summary helped clarify that I should remove NULLS and zero values from my results table before using the Percentile_Cont function as you suggested. Thanks again.